# Spring Boot opening a modal if there are errors using Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to validate a modal, and right now I can't make it open using Thymeleaf.
I have a table, and for each row I have a different modal, the modal ID takes its name myModal + the id of the object from the table

```
<div class="modal" th:id="*{'myModal'+{object.ID}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="#myModal" aria-hidden="true">
```

If there are errors for the object I'm updating in the modal (if I receive the param err) I want to make the modal open. I can validate the object and everything, but I don't know how to use Thymeleaf to take the ID of that object that I validated
I can make the modal open when there are errors only if I hard-code the ID - for example the ID 20

```
<script th:inline="javascript" th:if="${param.err}">$("#myModal20").modal("show");</script>
```

In the Controller when I verify if it has errors or not, I can send a model attribute "id-modal" and I think I can put it in the place of the hard-coded '20' using Thymeleaf, but I don't know how, can someone help? I keep receiving the error in the browser conole when I'm trying to do it "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 'myModal'+${id-modal}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use a dash `-` in your model attributes.  The expression `${id-modal}` means to subtract the value of `modal` from `id` -- literally the math expressions `id - modal`.  Once you've changed that (I will use `modalId` in this example), your JavaScript could look something like this.  (Also, see the [documentation on JavaScript inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#javascript-inlining).)

```
<script th:inline="javascript" th:if="${param.err}">
  let id = /*[[${modalId}]]*/ 0;
  $("#myModal" + id).modal("show");
</script>
```

(I'd probably also surround it with the jQuery document ready, but you might not want/need that.)